# look & feel native for android ios and windows phone with phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone

I need to develop an application for ios, android and windows phone (the same funcionality for each platform) with phonegap but i wanted to make native look & feel for each platform, i´m a web developer and i want to introduce myself in app´s development too but i´m newbie and i have lot of doubts...I read about framework 7, onsen and ionic but as i can see these are frameworks only for ios(or am i wrong?), are there some for android and windows phone?? These frameworks are like jquery ui where you put the classes to the elements and the framework apply the styles???I´m pretty lost in this area...sorry and thanks!!!

Comment: you are wrong, all the frameworks support iOS and android, some of them even WP. Framework 7 looks like iOS native apps, onsen an ionic doesn't look like any native app, they have chosen to use their own UI. You can use Intel's App Framework, they use different css for each platform

Comment: i expressed bad, i understand that these frameworks support all this platforms, what i meant is if there are specific frameworks for make native look & file for each platform, like framework7 that looks like a native ios app, i wanted the same for android an the same for windows phone...because it would be strange to use framework 7 for example for a windows phone app or android...
another thing... do you know good resources in spanish if it could be possible to learn well about phonegap/cordova for making apps??

Comment: Then as I said, the only one I know that applies different css for each platform trying to get a native look is Intel's App Framework. For resources you can look into phonegap.es or phonegapspain.com

Comment: Even tough framework7 documentation says it only supports IOS/Android, the library is still just CSS/JavaScript which means that on Windows 8.1 it looks like a responsive website.

Give it a go with this example app layout from fw7: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/tree/master/dist

Answer (score 0):

Try http://chocolatechip-ui.com/themes.html :) ... On this page you can see it's different themes in action.